# Redirect Permanent in Virtual Host apache configuration behaving not as expected

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

I have multiple domains pointing to the same IP.
RedirectPermanent works fine for all domains IF and only IF the pages are NOT existing, and I get the 404 default page of my website.
If I type in the browser a page actually existing, the redirect doesn't work, since I can access that page from all domains pointing to that IP.

Thus, if I type the url domaintoredirect1.com/page/not/existing,
I'm getting domainiwant.com/page/not/existing (redirect working fine)

If I type domaintoredirect1.com/page/existing
I don't get any redirect  and the url remains domaintoredirect1.com/page/existing

Why is this happening?

I also would like to redirect the www to the not www versione of the domain, but the redirect doesn't work in that case either: I get both version and no redirection.

I also would like to redirect another domain extension (.org to .com), and the www to the not www version of the domain, but the redirect doesn't work in these case either: I'm gettin www...org and notwww...org without redirections to notwww...com.

In these last cases, I've checked that domain with and without www are registered both with an A record (May this be the reason?).
In the other cases (domainsiwanttoredirect), the www version is registered as CNAME and I can access the www version only (the not www version gets redirected to the www one).

This is the **VirtulHost configuration** found in sites-available

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domaintoredirect1.com
ServerAlias domaintoredirect1.com
Redirect permanent "/" "https://domainiwant.com/en/about-us/domaintoredirect1/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domaintoredirect2.com
ServerAlias domaintoredirect.com
Redirect permanent "/" "https://domainiwant.com/en/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domainiwant.org
ServerAlias  domainiwant.org
Redirect permanent "/" "https://domainiwant.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domainiwant.com
Redirect permanent "/" "https://domainiwant.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domainiwant.com
Redirect permanent "/" "https://domainiwant.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Location />
        Require all denied
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm adding the **ssl_configuration file** also

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>


<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName   website-ws.domainIwant.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainIwant.com.22092020.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainIwant-com.key
SSLCipherSuite stuff...
SSLProtocol stuff...
SSLCipherSuite stuff...


#SSLProxyEngine on

<Location />
ProxyPass  http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#        AllowOverride All

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName www.domainToRedirect1.com
ServerAlias domainToRedirect1.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainToRedirect1.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/nginx_kmdevel.key

SSLCipherSuite stuff
SSLProtocol stuff
SSLCipherSuite stuff

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#        AllowOverride All

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName www.domainIwant.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainIwant.com.22092020.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainIwant-com.key

SSLCipherSuite stuff
SSLProtocol stuff
SSLCipherSuite stuff

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#        AllowOverride All

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName domainIwant.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainIwant.com.22092020.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainIwant-com.key

SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#        AllowOverride All

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName www.domainIwant.it
ServerAlias domainIwant.it
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainIwant.it.2020.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainIwant_2020.key

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.domainToRedirect2.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias domainToRedirect2.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domainToRedirect2.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domainToRedirect2.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
#        AllowOverride All

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


ServerName rcs.domainIwant.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainIwant.com.22092020.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domainIwant-com.key

SSLCipherSuite stuff
SSLProtocol stuff
SSLCipherSuite stuff

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would also ask what does **ServerName default** mean, since in the apache_conf file I don't find any reference to a
I'm copying the **apache config** file also

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: If the browser is interpreting your URLs as https by default, then the answer is within the configurations for the HTTPS virtual hosts, running on port 443, which you don't show here.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I've added all the configuration files at my disposal. How do I make the browser interpret my URLs as https by default?

Comment: Add an [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to your https sites, so once the client gets redirected there from http, it'll stay there in the future.